# Reordering declarations with use-package: Why does this work?

Tags: use-package

I'm reorganising my `init.el` a bit and I've realised that it contains the following set of `use-package` declarations: (simplified slightly)

```lisp
(use-package hasky-extensions
  :config
  (general-define-key
   :states '(normal visual insert emacs)
   :keymap 'haskell-mode-map
   :prefix "K"
   :non-normal-prefix "C-)"
   "xx" 'hasky-extensions
   "xd" 'hasky-extensions-browse-docs
   "hh"  'hoogle
   "hH"  'haskell-hoogle-lookup-from-local))

;; ...
;; then, a bit later:

(use-package general)
```

Arguably this shouldn't work, as `general-define-key` is called before `general` is `require`d through the `use-package` declaration. However, it turns out to work just fine - I get no errors and can use all the keybindings I have defined. Why does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed `general` through `package.el` and are using `package-initialize`, then the answer is that installation produces a `general-autoloads.el` file which `package-initialize` loads. That file contains an autoload for `general-define-key`, which means that whenever you cal `general-define-key` the `general` package will be loaded.

(If you installed `general` in some other way and didn't generate the autoloads file, or if you do have the autoload file but don't use `package-initialize` or in some way load it, then we'd need more information to figure things out.)

Comment: This sounds right, especially since I've noticed other packages autoloading.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the answer is pure luck!  `use-package` often defers loading a package until it is called so that, as long as `general` got called first (perhaps by some other package), you are golden.

You can control the situation by putting an `:after general` in the `use-package` form for `hasky-extensions` and then luck will no longer be required...

Comment: I don't think this is it - putting `message` calls for debugging seems to indicate that `hasky-stack` is indeed being loaded before `general`.